# How to draw a quadratic Bézier curve on a linear framebuffer

Tags: c, algorithm, curve, bezier

As the title says, I want to draw a quadratic Bézier curve on a linear framebuffer (aka plotting pixels).

I already have a function that's drawing a cubic Bézier curve according to https://www.joshondesign.com/2018/07/11/bezier-curves (I translated the javascript into C like this https://gist.github.com/cheyao/a736a58c4cf683eabea2aa2a87718ef1#file-cubic-c) which works *fine*.

And now I tried to convert it into drawing a quadratic Bézier curve (like this https://gist.github.com/cheyao/a736a58c4cf683eabea2aa2a87718ef1#file-flatness-c), which is looking not-fine for me (too not curvish).

I also tried to brutal force it like this

```c
void quadratic_bezier_curve(const Vector2 p[3], const color_t color) {
    for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.001) {
        putPixel((uint32_t) ((1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].x + t * t * p[2].x),
                 (uint32_t) ((1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].y + t * t * p[2].y), color);
    }
}
```

Which makes the like look bold.

So my question comes: Does anyone know some better algorithms to draw a (quadratic) Bézier curves? (I need it for font rendering.)

Comment: Note that if you want to draw "true" pixels (without subpixels) then using 1000 points per curve is kind of crazy, you're going to recompute the same pixel over and over again at that resolution. If you only want "new pixels", don't draw the curve like this, draw it using the [bresenham algorithm](https://zingl.github.io/bresenham.html).

Comment: I know that it's kinda crazy, but since my screen is 1024 pixels wide, if I have a like from the left of the screen to the right, using like 100 points per curve isn't enough. But thanks a lot for your link!

Comment: While true, the solution there is generally to look pick a number of steps that's lower than you need to draw every pixel, and then simply draw lines between each point (no bresenham needed in that case), instead of drawing each point as a pixel. Even for cubic curves at large size, you generally need less than 100 steps for a good looking curve (and sampling with a uniform `t` step automatically spaces "easily approximated by lines" segments far apart, while spacing "this needs more, small, segments" close together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. Found a mistake, that for flatness we need to check absolute values. And there was a typo that `p[1].y` was used twice instead of once. So it would be like:

```
static int32_t quadratic_flatness(const Vector2 p[3]) {
    return abs((int32_t) p[1].x - (((int32_t) p[0].x + (int32_t) p[2].x) / 2))
         + abs((int32_t) p[1].y - (((int32_t) p[0].y + (int32_t) p[2].y) / 2));
}
```

Live example in JS (click 'Run code snippet' button and start clicking with mouse left button on the canvas):

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';

// get canvas 2D context and set him correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

let points = [];

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);

function quadratic_split_curve(p) { // out[2][3]
    const p12 = midpoint(p[0], p[1]);
    const p23 = midpoint(p[1], p[2]);
    const p123 = midpoint(p12, p23);
  return [
        [p[0], p12, p123],
        [p123, p23, p[2]]
  ];
}

function quadratic_flatness(p) {
    const result = Math.abs(p[1].x - (Math.floor( p[0].x + p[2].x) / 2)) +  Math.abs(p[1].y - (Math.floor( p[0].y +  p[2].y) / 2));
  return result;
}

function quadratic_bezier_curve(p, color) {
    if (quadratic_flatness(p) < 2) {
        line(p[0], p[2], color);
        return;
    } else {
        const split = quadratic_split_curve(p);
        quadratic_bezier_curve(split[0], color);
        quadratic_bezier_curve(split[1], color);
    }
}

function midpoint(a, b) {
    return {
    x: (a.x + b.x)/2,
    y: (a.y + b.y)/2
  }
}

// new position from mouse event
function setPosition(e) {
 if(points.length >= 3) {
        points = [];
  }
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  draw();
}

function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
function dot(point) {
    ctx.fillRect(point.x-1,point.y-1,3,3);
}
function line(a, b, color) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    ctx.lineTo(b.x, b.y); 
    ctx.stroke();
}
function draw() {
    clear();
  for(const point of points) {
    dot(point);
  }
  
  if(points.length == 3) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    quadratic_bezier_curve(points, '#c0392b');
  }
  
  if(points.length > 1) {
  
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#3039cb77';
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    
    for(i=1; i<points.length; i++) {

      ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y); 
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  return;
}
```

Comment: This code snippet does not appear to draw anything. Remember that the snippet only renders 200px high.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , you need to click to place 3 points there, then quadratic curve will be drawn.